# Get text to wrap around other text when inside a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I need to put a superscript number (for disclaimer) before some rich text disclaimer text. The rich text is deeply inside some divs with their own styling. How can I get it to wrap around the superscript like this?

```
1 sometext sometext sometext sometext ...
sometext sometext ...
```

Instead what I am able to do is one of these:

```
1 sometext sometext ...
  ... sometext sometext
```

Or

```
1
sometext sometext ...
... sometext sometext
```

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

sup {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.RichText {
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <sup>1</sup>
  <div class="RichText">
    <div class="RichTextStyled">
      <div contenteditable="false" translate="no" class="ProseMirror">
        <p>I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines. I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines. I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks like the result you want. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm assuming you can't change the HTML, you can always float the SUP left and give it a margin right to space it out.

```css
sup {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.RichText {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <sup>1</sup>
  <div class="RichText">
    <div class="ProseMirror">
      <p>I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines. I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines. I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way? For some reason my production app isn't accepting the float, I don't know what it is yet. I updated the code with the exact code but your example still works, so not sure.

Comment: @Alien, does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/02kthyv1/7/) solve your problem? I have used flex to align the sup & the content.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli no / that pushes everything to the right of the number, looking for it to wrap around the number.

Comment: @Alien You mean the text content to wrap the sup, right? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3qbnmyh5/1/) I used positioning to make it inside the content div if that's why meant.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli try posting an answer instead commenting. That will allow you to communicate about your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `margin-left` and `margin-right`: auto; and   `position: absolute;`

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

sup {
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.RichText {
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <sup>1</sup>
  <div class="RichText">
    <div class="RichTextStyled">
      <div contenteditable="false" translate="no" class="ProseMirror">
        <p>I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines. I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines. I am some rich text that stretches over multiple lines.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```